# When convert PHP to UTF-8 Ajax data.status == "success" stop working

Tags: php, ajax, utf-8

My website was in ISO 8859-1, so I decided to change it to UTF-8.

Now, MySQL is in UTF-8, my PHP pages are saved as UTF-8 (no BOM), my SQL connection is set to UTF-8.

The problem is, my Ajax `data.status == "success"` is not working.

PHP:

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/json'); include("config.php");
include("verifica.php");

session_start(); $user = $_SESSION["user"]; $pinsid=$_POST['id'];

$chkpinu=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE post='$pinsid' AND
user='$user'"); $chknum=mysql_num_rows($chkpinu);

 if($chknum==0){   $add=mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes (id, user,
post) VALUES ('','$user','$pinsid')");   $response['status'] =
'success';  }
      echo json_encode(array_values($response));

?>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({    type: "POST",    cache: false,    url: "like.php",   
data: info,

   success: function(data){
    if( data.status == "success" ) {

     $("#loading").ajaxComplete(function(){}).slideUp();
     $('#like'+I).fadeOut(200).hide();
     $('#unlike'+I).fadeIn(200).show();
     $('#newlike'+I).fadeIn(100).show();
     $("#numberlikes"+I).text(""+number);  
    }

  }  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do console.log(data.status) and paste it here.

Comment: Do a console.log(data);

Comment: "success"! but if I use: if( data == "success" ) { it not work.

Comment: It says "success" because you are using array_values() function on the PHP code. data == "success" should work. data.status == "success" should work if you remove the array_values() function.

Comment: Thank you! I get the "success", remove the quotes and check it normally!

Answer (score 0):

When you use array_values() you lose the ['status'] key, which is converted to [0].

Use this:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

Instead of this:

```
echo json_encode(array_values($response));
```

Comment: Thank you! I get the "success", remove the quotes and check it normally!